# Is there any drawback to using '\n' at the start instead of end?

Tags: c++, newline, cout

Mostly I see people using `\n` at the end of string but putting `\n` at the beginning makes more sense to me since now I don't have to keep track of what will be printed next.
For example-

```
std::cout<<"Some string\n";  //syntax 1
```

Suppose after this the control goes to some other function where I don't need a new line but using this syntax is enforcing that newline to be inserted unless I can think ahead and keep track of whether next line needs to be printed in newline or not.

```
std::cout<<"\nSome string";  //syntax 2
```

But by using the second syntax I can avoid such things and I only have to worry about the current statement.

Question- Is it only a personal preference of using either of the 2 syntaxes or is there any drawback to second one over the  first one?

Comment: The drawback of syntax 2 may be you may forget to print a newline at end of output.

Comment: Placement of newlines interacts with line buffering.  May or may not be a problem, make sure you understand how line buffering treats newline characters.

Comment: Output is buffered.  If you don't print a newline, then the output may not print until you flush the buffer or read from cin.

Comment: @MikeCAT Could that cause a problem? Why would I need newline at end of output when every output itself is in newline? Sorry if im missing something here

Comment: *Why would I need newline at end of output when every output itself is in newline?*  With syntax#2, the beginning of every output is a newline, but not the characters that come after the newline.  Then at the end of the program, there's no final newline.  Aww, sad panda.

Comment: `'\n'` is often call **end**-of-line for a reason.

Comment: In C, a file that lacks ending with a final `'\n'` may/may not meets the requirements of a text file.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes this is generally because of the platform on which the compiler is ran, and probably isn't related to the format of a C program

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel Not discussing the format of a C program's file, but of a test stream.  Standard library has "A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is  implementation-defined."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sorry, I thought you meant the format of a C program because your sentence started with "In C".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not at all "personal preference" - the two solutions are semantically different.  You would use one over the other when the requirements of your application demand it.

One critical point though is on many platforms `\n` causes any buffered text to be flushed and the text to be output.  If you delay the `\n` you may not see the output immediately until the next `\n` which may not be deterministic or timely.

Comment: Is the extra `\n` required on some platforms only there to flush buffered text? I would assume there possibly would be other purposes to it, but that might also be because of my limited experience with those platforms

Comment: No of course not; it is there _only_ to start a new line.  Anything else that happens is a side-effect. If the platform uses line-buffered output it will only output when 1) a newline character is buffered 2) the buffer is filled, 3) the buffer is explicitly flushed or 4) the process terminates and the system flushes the buffer.  On windows, console output is normally immediate.  It is a platform dependent thing, not a language thing.  Also it is not an "extra" newline - it is just a newline.  In what way is it "extra"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these syntaxes according to your needs. A choice will matter in case of recurring statements such as loops and recursive functions where a string needs to be printed.

The first syntax `std::cout<<"\n String";` will however always begin printing after it has inserted a new line, which might not suit your purpose if it's the first line that's being printed.

But I believe it's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: It is really not an "matter of personal preference".  It is a matter of semantics.

Comment: The behaviour of newline is platform also dependent.  On Windows which prints to the "console" outputs immediately whilst Linux, and Unix which print to a terminal emulation, use line buffering (by default).  So "always" is not strictly true.

Answer (score 0):

In unix systems, when the content of standard output is intended to be the input of another program, printing a `\n` last generally means being able to interact with a larger set of command line utilities.

In the end it depends on what you want to do with standard output. That's why it's possible to write both ways.

Comment: Just FYI, it is requirement for text file to end with new line in many Nixes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context you are writing your output in.

### Syntax 1

If you want to make sure that your output begins with a new line and you can't tell if the cursor is at the beginning of a line you would favor syntax 1.

Example without '\n':

```
Output you don't control
----------------------------
Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3Some string of your function.
```

Example with '\n':

```
Output you don't control
----------------------------
Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 
Some string of your function.
```

### Syntax 2

On the other hand, if you are done with your output it is good practice to finish with a new line so the upcoming output doesn't have to be concerned in what state you left the cursor in.

Example without '\n':

```
Some string of your function.Output you don't control
----------------------------
Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
```

Example with '\n':

```
Some string of your function.
Output you don't control
----------------------------
Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
```